# How to customize the position of a scroll bar in a web container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

Currently, I am trying to create a data grid that allow user to click on the item in ColA and the right side screen will show another hidden container with detail info.

I have a fixed height div that holds a table as my data grid, and because the 'overflow' is set to 'auto', it will have a scroll bar on the right side of the div that allow user to scroll the entire data grid. (See image below)
[image]

However, in my case, I would like to move the scroll bar next to the 'colA' and still allow user to scroll the entire data grid. (see image below)
[image]

Right now, I can put the scroll bar next to ColA as I define another fix height div there and set 'overflow' to 'auto', but of course, that will only allow me to scroll the ColA only.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to meet my requirement with some CSS setting?
2. If the answer of 1 is No, can I achieve my goal by creating an event handler for the colA scroll bar? (could you please provide some sample code?)
3. If the answer of 1 is No, is there any opensource tool that can support this kind of need?

===============
Here is the Code of the table part (irrelevant style removed)===========

```
<td colspan="2">
<div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto; margin: 1px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr><td><p> data Item 1</p></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p> data Item 2</p></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p> data Item 3</p></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p> data Item 4</p></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td><p> related item 1</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 1</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 1</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><p> related item 2</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 2</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 2</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><p> related item 3</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 3</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><p> related item 4</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 4</p></td>
            <td><p> related item 4</p></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any help is great appreciated.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put scrollbar on column a and then you can change column b scrollposition like this:

```
var setScrollHeight = function(e){
    colA = $(".col-a")[0];
    colB = $(".col-b")[0];

    console.log(e);
    var scrollPercent = colA.scrollTop / (colA.scrollHeight - parseInt(colA.clientHeight));

    if(e.originalEvent.deltaY !== undefined && e.originalEvent.target != colA)
        scrollPercent += e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0 ? -0.16 : 0.16; 

    colA.scrollTop = (colA.scrollHeight - colA.clientHeight) * scrollPercent;
    colB.scrollTop = (colB.scrollHeight - colB.clientHeight) * scrollPercent;
}

$(".col-a").scroll( setScrollHeight);
$(".container").on("mousewheel DOMMouseWheel onmousescroll", setScrollHeight);
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvm7ujce/4/)

Update: Default scrollbar things now works

Comment: thank you so much! I have applied this method with my code, it works as I envisioned. One follow up question: How can I apply the customized setScrollHeight function to dragging the scroll bar/clicking on the scroll bar, clicking the arrow button inside scroll bar? (Basically incorporate this function for all scroll bar related event)

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much for the help! It's definitely worth to learn this technique.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most you can do:

```css
.Container
{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.Content
{
    height: 300px;
}

.Flipped
{
    direction: rtl;
}
.Content
{
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<h1>Normal</h1>
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Content"></div>
</div>

<h1>Flipped</h1>
<div class="Container Flipped">
    <div class="Content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know we can flip the side of scroll bar but that's not exactly what I want..